# Trying to compile adxl345 as a module in 4.4.54-ti-r93 kernel but get error

Tags: linux, build, linux-device-driver

I have downloaded below debian image from latest images site

```
Debian 8.7 2017-03-19 4GB SD LXQT
```

I have attached a adxl345 accelerometer, and with user space tools its working fine.
Now I am trying to attach a kernel driver i.e in adxl345. I put the source files in

```
/home/debian/Desktop/adxl345
```

and issued make.
I get this error

```
root@beaglebone:/home/debian/Desktop/adxl345# make
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.54-ti-r93/build M=/home/debian/Desktop/adxl345 modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.4.54-ti-r93/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

I checked

```
root@beaglebone:/lib/modules/4.4.54-ti-r93# ls 
extra          modules.builtin  modules.devname  modules.symbols.bin
kernel         modules.builtin.bin  modules.order
modules.alias      modules.dep      modules.softdep
modules.alias.bin  modules.dep.bin  modules.symbols
```

there is no build directory. I tried to update kernel headers

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-linux-headers-4.4.54-ti-r93
```

but it says

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-linux-headers-4.4.54-ti-r93
```

How I am going to build the drivers?

Comment: `linux-headers-linux-headers-4.4.54-ti-r93` - You have repeated "linux-headers" **twice**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not updated cache

sudo apt-get update

Once updated we can check at /lib/modules
there will be a build directory.
Now it should be building.